# How to stop airflow?

Tags: airflow

I wanto to stop airflow as it is blocking port 8080. I tired:

```
sudo systemctl stop airflow
```

> Failed to stop airflow.service: Unit airflow.service not loaded.

Which did not work. I still see airflow running with `top`.

Comment: you can use `kill` command, find the PID through `top` or `ps`, and use `kill -9 <pid>`

Comment: I am not sure this is on-topic on SO. Seems more suited for [Server Fault]?